# Changes in Meta API [Reporting for Purchases and Conversion Value broken]

Tags: facebook, pipeline

I have connected Facebook Ads API to BigQuery with a tool called Hevo to make reports in Looker Studio for Marketing purpuses.

Last week, the fields from the API I used (`adds_to_cart`, `action_values_purchases` & `purchases`) started returning null values and after making a brand new connection, the fields seem to be missing from the '`ad_insights`' table from the API.

Now there's much new fields for purchases like '`fb_pixel_purcheses`' but none seem to be returning values.

How can I know which field to use to get purchase data on our reports or how could I solve this null values from '`fb_pixel_purcheses`' and other fields.

Thanks so much hope someone can give me a hand!